# Decoded TFRecord has wrong size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am using TensorFlows DeepLab and wanted to see if my data was converted correctly to tfrecords. I used the predefined `download_and_convert_ade20k.sh` and below code to decode it back:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

feature_desc = {
    'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/filename': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/format': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value='jpeg'),
    'image/height': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'image/segmentation/class/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/segmentation/class/format': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value='png'),
}

def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_desc)

raw_image_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('ADE20K/tfrecord/train-00000-of-00004.tfrecord')

parsed_image_dataset = raw_image_dataset.map(_parse_image_function)

for image_features in parsed_image_dataset:
    img = tf.io.decode_raw(image_features['image/encoded'], tf.uint8).numpy()
    seg = tf.io.decode_raw(image_features['image/segmentation/class/encoded'], tf.uint8).numpy()
```

I have two problems. First I don't know the datatype of the images before they were encoded. I am guessing `tf.uint8` because it is the only one working that also outputs values between 0 and 255. On the other hand the obtained image is in 1D (as expected) but not long enough to reshape it into its original shape. The decoded image is of length 48836 whereas the original height and width is (512, 612) which equals 313344 pixels in total.